ora-12715 - Oracle GoldaneGate can not connect to database
I install Oracle 21c database and Oracle GoldaneGate 21.3 on Windows server, I can connect to my PDB using sqlplus and SqlDeveloper from another pc, but when try to dblogin from GGSCI get error
this is my environment I set in my server:
ORACLE_HOME     = D:\oracle21c\WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = D:\oracle21c\WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home\lib
TNS_ADMIN       = D:\oracle21c\app\oracle\homes\OraDB21Home1\network\admin
NLS_LANG        = AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8MSWIN1256
OGG_HOME        = OGG_HOME
PATH            = ...;D:\oracle21c\WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home\bin;D:\oracle21c\WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home\lib

get this error:
GGSCI (Oracle-test) 2> dblogin userid ggs@mypdb
Password: 
Error: Failed to initialize timezone information. Check location of ORACLE_HOME.

I set ORA_TZFILE in environment
ORA_TZFILE = D:\oracle21c\WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home\oracore\zoneinfo\timezlrg_35.dat

now I get this error:
GGSCI (Oracle-test) 2> dblogin userid ggs@mypdb
Password:
Error: OCI Error ORA (status = 12715-Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12715
)

I change mgr file in dirprm like this:
PORT 7809
USERID ggs@mypdb, PASSWORD ggs

and when run start manager in ggsci, have this error:
2024-11-25T02:29:57.852-0800  INFO    OGG-03541  Oracle GoldenGate Manager for Oracle, MGR.prm:  Oracle Environment Variables: 
                              TNS_ADMIN = D:\oracle21c\WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home\network\admin
                              PATH = C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;D:\oracle21c\WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home\bin;D:\oracle21c\WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home\lib;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\oracle21c\ords\bin;D:\ggs;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.
2024-11-25T02:29:57.978-0800  ERROR   OGG-00303  Oracle GoldenGate Manager for Oracle, MGR.prm:  OCI Error ORA (status = ١٢٧١٥-Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12715
                              ).
2024-11-25T02:29:57.994-0800  ERROR   OGG-01668  Oracle GoldenGate Manager for Oracle, MGR.prm:  PROCESS ABENDING.

I don't config extract,pump or replicate!

might be related to character set .. however, checking here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/goldengate/core/19.1/admin/supported-character-sets.html  it seems like your character set: ar8mswin1256  is supported ...  O.o   is the database you're connecting to configured to same character set?  (can you show "select * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS where PARAMETER like '%CHAR%SET%'" from the database (not via GG .. just directly from the DB?)

@Ditto yes I check database, it use same character set.
I login in windows using Administrator user, It's Ok? or need login with user that created when install Oracle db?

I don't believe that's causing your issue here .. but I honestly can't tell. I'm unable to reproduce, and never seen this before .. so can't help beyond that possibility :(  Sorry.  Might have to open an Oracle SR if you have support with them.
